# Way to specify model version number

Tags: mlflow

Is there a way to specify version number to the models during registration?

Could not find anything in the documentation regarding this

Answer (score 0):

[Versioning is by auto-incrementing integers](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html#concepts) as of now (May'23).

> Each registered model can have one or many versions. When a new model is added to the Model Registry, it is added as version 1. Each new model registered to the same model name increments the version number.

However, there is a [feature request on MLFlow's GitHub](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/7280) which calls for enabling custom versions (like strings). An obstacle is that such a (rigid) design assumption propagated through the code base. I encourage to upvote. :-)

If your use-case is about annotating the model with strings (to be somewhat organized and queried) then tagging in the existing implementation may be a workaround.